# Function signature for potentially failed unique_ptr move?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, move-semantics

Say I am writing a `enqueue()` function that takes in a `unique_ptr`, but I only want to claim its ownership when enqueue returns success. If the queue is full I want to leave the `unique_ptr` intact (user can retry with the same item later)

```
bool enqueue(std::unique_ptr&& item){
  if(!vector.full()){
    vector.emplace(std::move(item));
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
// usage
auto item_ptr = make_unique<>();
while(!enqueue(std::move(item_ptr))){
// item_ptr is not moved
}
```

I can also define the function to take a lvalue reference instead

```
bool enqueue(std::unique_ptr& item)
while(!enqueue(item_ptr)){
// item_ptr is not moved
}
```

I am not sure which one to pick, they all seemed a little anti-patterned since usually `std::move` indicates the deletion of a unique_ptr (most of the time, I work with function that takes `unique_ptr` by value), maybe there's a better solution?

Comment: Think what happens if you do `while (!enqueue(make_unique<>()))`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a unique_ptr from your function. If it failed return the original. If it succeeded return an empty unique_ptr.

Then you could call it like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int counter = 10;

template <typename T> std::unique_ptr<T> enqueue(std::unique_ptr<T> p) {
  if (--counter == 0)
    return std::unique_ptr<T>();
  return p;
}

int main() {
  auto item_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(8);
  while (item_ptr = enqueue(std::move(item_ptr))) {
    std::cout << "looping\n";
  }
  std::cout << "moved\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Actually, I'd better go try this out. Yeah my first idea had a bug. Ripping out that `!` from the while loop. Always test. :-)

Comment: you can remove `std::move` in the return part, RVO will handle the moving.

Comment: @МоргуновВладислав: Only if I change the parameter to remove the `&&`. Then it works. Updating.

Answer (score 4):

The first version with the RValue reference accepts a temporary.
Thus, if the move didn't happen you have an instance in a temporary `std::unique_ptr` which will be deleted soon.
This is what makes me uncertain whether it's a good choice (or inviting for surprising effects).

At least, one should be aware of this.

Concerning the question

> what happens if you do while (!enqueue(make_unique<>()))...

I made an MCVE (just to be sure):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
  Test() { std::cout << "Test::Test()\n"; }
  ~Test() { std::cout << "Test::~Test()\n"; }
};

bool enqueue(std::unique_ptr<Test>&& item)
{
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3 && !enqueue(std::make_unique<Test>()); ++i);
}
```

Output:

```
Test::Test()
Test::~Test()
Test::Test()
Test::~Test()
Test::Test()
Test::~Test()
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bcb73ff4d854655)

If it's intended to prevent "abuse" and ensure that `enqueue()` isn't called for temporaries the RValue version could be dropped.

Comment: good catch, lvalue reference cannot point to temp. Although in this case, I would argue that solution 1 is actually better since `enqueue(std::make_unique<Test>())` should be a valid use case, I designed my API to allow reuse of input value, but if use decide to do, say fire and forget, its their freedom, non?

Comment: @watashiSHUN I'm really uncertain. (Hence, I tried to word it "carefully".) ;-) It could be intended or not intended. IMHO, the existence of the RValue ref. version expresses that's intended by the API designer that non-processed arguments are just thrown away. (Actually, the damage is limited - just a useless construction/destruction but nothing is lost or leaked. Though, of course, it depends what the pointee contains...)

Answer (score 0):

The frame of  mind I like to have about `std::move` is that it's only me indicating I'm fine with the object being modified. It's not about causing deletion, it's about giving permission for *potentially* destructive stuff to happen.

Your first option seems OK to me. Callers have to explicitly give permission by marking their lvalues with `std::move`, and they can check if something indeed happened by inspecting the return value of the function. So they won't have objects they care about suddenly disappearing. It's good *enough* IMO.

But like [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68204663/817643) said, this version also gives the option of passing a temporary `unique_ptr`. If the pointless work in that case bothers you, then we should probably go with another approach.

One guideline I like to take from the Google Style Guide sometimes, is that [input/]output parameters are passed by non-owning raw pointer. This basically restricts them to being lvalues, while retaining the explicitness required in allowing for their modification. So you could do this:

```
bool enqueue(std::unique_ptr<T>* item){
  if(!vector.full()){
    vector.emplace(std::move(*item));
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// usage
auto item_ptr = make_unique<T>();
while(!enqueue(&item_ptr)){
// item_ptr is not modified
}
```

Under such a style guide, the address-of operator `&` serves the same purpose as `std::move`. It's us telling the function: "Go ahead, modify it if you need to."

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems kind of tricky to me, as you're passing the `unique_ptr`, but it may or may not be claimed, so there's a need to somehow handle this kind of behavior: like, returning an empty `unique_ptr` in case of a success or an error/success code, doing redundant or hard-to-understand checks and so on. I think what you can do is check if your queue has free space externally, with the help of full() method or something like that. Then your code will look something like that:

```
if(!full()) {
    enqueue(std::move(...));
}
```